# Nifi ORC File size

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-nifi, orc

I have a NIFI flow that gets some data from an eventhub, I get those flowfiles and first I merge them, I convert them from JSON to AVRO, then I convert it from AVRO to ORC and last I use a PutHDFS to write them in a Datalake. This data will be queried with spark and Hive.

So what I would like to get is all this process to leave 250 MB orc files in the datalake with ZLIB compression as its recommended.

Right now the problem that I have is that im getting at the end with the compression very small files, not getting even to the 150 MB far from my goal.

I have tried several approaches configuring the MergeContent in different ways, putting that the max age for each file should be 15 minutes, 2 GB of minimun size and 300000 size of flowfiles. This approach leaves me usually with a flowfile of 1.4GB size that in the end in the last processor leaves me with a file more or less of 120 MB.

So my goal its, get the JSON files and leave them in the DataLake in ORC format with a size of 250 MB.

Is my approach not correct? Any advice? Thanks.

If you need to see my configs I could add them.
[MergeContent configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/id0eS.png)

Comment: Why is that a problem? A few years ago, the default HDFS block size was 64 MB. And with ORC files, it's the internal stripe size that makes a real difference, not the overall file size.

Comment: If the 150 MB file size really makes you feel bad, then check the `ALTER TABLE ... CONCATENATE` command in Hive >> https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-AlterTable/PartitionConcatenate

Comment: hey samson thnaks, I'm setting the default stripe size of 60 MB is that too much for the size of the files? Thanks